# MongoDB join / update

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like your opinion about the process i set up:

I have two collections:

> Clients : { client_id, client_type }
>
> Orders : { order_id, client_id,order_amount, order_valid }

Based on those collections, I would like to calculate, among others, the number of valid orders by client type.

So I would like to join the two collections and add the client_type into my orders collection

I did it this way, but i don't find this solution very effective.

```
db.clients.find (
    {},
    {
        client_id : 1,
        client_type : 1
    }   
).forEach(function (pClient) {
        
    db.orders.update (
        {
            client_id : pClient.client_id
        },
        { $set : {
            client_type : pClient.client_type
            
        }}, 
        { 
            multi : true
        }
    )
});
```

Do you have an idea of how to ameliorate this process?

Comment: It's better to put everything in one document. {Client id; Client type, {Order Id, Order Amount, Order Valid}}. Then you can just use the aggregate framework.

Comment: The collections Orders and Clients are loaded from external files, i can't do that.

Comment: If using MongoDB 3.2 [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) does a left outer join to another collection in the same database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing.

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm using MongoDB 2.6, `$lookup` is not available

Comment: Let me guess, the data in the collection spans to millions? You could use the bulk api to update the collection.

Comment: Yes, i will try using the bulk and check the performances differences between the two methods, thanks

Comment: Do you have any Final answer for this question ? Mr. @Mouette

Answer (score 1):

So, this is the fastest solution i found:

```
var bulk = db.orders.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var bulk_counter = 0;

db.clients.find (
    {},
    {
        client_id : 1,
        client_type : 1
    }   
).forEach(function (pClient) {
    bulk.find(
        {
            client_id : pClient.client_id
        }
    ).update(
        { $set : {
             client_type : pClient.client_type
        }}, 
    )

    bulk_counter++;
    if (bulk_counter % 1000 == 0) 
    {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.m_recipient_indicators.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        }
});

if (bulk_counter % 1000 != 0) 
{ 
    bulk.execute(); 
}
```